# Call checkbox value if checked from html file in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, google-apps-script

I have two files: myPage.html and myCode.gs in google scripts. I have deployed the html file as a web app, and I have figured out (with help) how to make the onclick event for the 'submit' button to trigger the emailTech function from the myCode.gs file just fine. I have also been able to insert the value from the text box in the html file into the email that is called from the onClick event.

I also have two check boxes and if checked, I would like to have their values entered into the email triggered by the onClick event. I have tried various versions of 'if checked then' statements both in the script tage of the html file and in the emailTech function but neither seem to work. Any suggestions?

myPage.html file:

```
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" value=" " name="techEmail" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkone" value="checkone" />Checkone
        <input type="checkbox" name="checktow" value="checktwo" />Checktwo
        <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
        google.script.run.emailTech(document.forms[0]);
    }
</script>
```

myCode.gs file:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage');
}

function emailTech(form){
//I want something along the lines of:
  //if form.checkone == "checked"{
    //var checkone = "checkone"
    //}
  //if form.checktwo == "checked"{
    //var checktwo = "checktwo"
    //}
  var nameBox = form.techEmail;
  var message = "This is the text box value" + nameBox + checkone + checktwo;
  MailApp.sendEmail("email@somewhere.com", "This is the subject", message );

}
```

Also, is there a way to clear the textbox and checkboxes when the submit button is clicked? I don't want to have a seperate reset button, I'd like this to reset and send the email with one click if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox input shouldn't be in a self-closing tag. (That's one that ends with `/>`.) You also need to align your `value` setting with what you'll look for in your handler ('checked'). Change your html like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkone" value="checked" >Checkone
    <input type="checkbox" name="checktow" value="checked" >Checktwo
```

Now in your server-side handler, you can just check for the presence of 'checkone' and/or 'checktwo', because they will only be delivered in the event when checked. You can alternatively check the value, as you were planning to.

Just remove the comments from your "wish", fix the syntax, and you're good!

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution- works perfectly! Thanks! Is it possible to clear the check boxes and text box with the onClick event without having to add another 'reset' button?

Comment: Your handler could explicitly reset each element in the form. See [this blog](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml) for a decent example.